# AngularJS view does not refresh when model is updated in nested methods

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am new to AngularJS and I am writing a small introduction web page in it. Here is the JS file:

```
// Create an Angular Module with the name as 'MyPersonalWebsiteApp'.
var myWebsiteApp = angular.module('MyPersonalWebsiteApp', [] );

myWebsiteApp.controller( 'dateAndTimeController', [ '$scope', '$interval', '$log', function( $scope, $interval, $log ) {

    $scope.counter = 0;
    var increaseCounter = function () {
        $scope.counter = $scope.counter + 1;
        console.log( $scope.counter );
    }

    //$interval(increaseCounter, 1000);    
    var today = new Date();
    $scope.today = today.getSeconds();
}]);

myWebsiteApp.controller( 'briefIntro', [ '$scope', '$timeout','$interval', '$log', function( $scope, $timeout, $interval, $log ) {

    var myJobProfile = "SOFTWARE DEVELOPER|";
    var myInterests = "FULL STACK DEVELOPEMENT ENTHUSIAST|"
    var myLocation = "HYDERABAD, INDIA";
    $scope.message = "";

    $scope.constructMessage = function( message ) {

        for( inx = 0; inx < message.length; ++inx )
        {
            $scope.message = $scope.message + message.charAt(inx);
            console.log("constructMessage" + $scope.message );
        }        
    }

    $scope.destructMessage = function( message ) {

        for( inx = message.length-1; inx >= 0; --inx )
        {
            $scope.message = $scope.message.substring(0, $scope.message.length - 1 );
            console.log("destructMessage" + $scope.message );
        }        
    }

    var displayMessage = function() {
        $scope.message = "EYU";
        $scope.constructMessage( myJobProfile );
        $scope.destructMessage( myJobProfile );

        // displayInfo( myInterests );
        // displayInfo( myLocation );

    }

    $interval( displayMessage, 200);
}]);
```

My HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="centered-text">
        <div class="aboutme-lg">I'M PAVAN DITTAKAVI</div>

        <p class="aboutme-sm-dyn" ng-controller="briefIntro">
            {{ message }}
        </p>

        <!-- Two BRs for better presentation. -->
        <br /><br />

        <!-- Navigation Buttons -->
        <div class="nav-options">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">
                <span class="fa fa-code" aria-hidden="true"><span class="nav-links"> My Activities</span></span>
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">
                <span class="fa fa-address-card" aria-hidden="true"><span class="nav-links"> My Resume</span></span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is even if the model had changed - `$scope.message`, it is not rendering in the HTML page. I noticed that update of this `$scope.message` in the method `displayMessage` displays the content in HTML. But I make use of two helper methods - `constructMessage` and `destructMessage` and inside them, I cannot get the view to be updated when the model changes.

What am I missing here? Is there any scope/inheritance that is coming into the picture that I am not able to see?. I read a tutorial on Udemy and I got to understand that SCOPE is a singleton. Please let me know what I could be missing.

Thanks,
Pavan.

Comment: Can you see the correct output in the console?

Comment: @AlonEitan I can see the correct output in the console.

Comment: Are you trying to do something [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/u6hxLtrc/1/)?

Comment: Yes, but that part is already working at my impl. I have three such strings which I would like to display in that format. And that is the reason why I parameterized the method.

Comment: This question was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers

Comment: @georgewag Is there anything that you would suggest me to add to my answer

Answer (score 0):

My bad. The reason why this piece of AngularJS code was not working was `$interval` gets invoked every 200ms. And each time it is run, the constructor and destructor methods are called and in the for loop, since there is no time delay as such, the content which I wanted to display just gets created and destroyed accordingly. And this happens in such a short time that it gives the impression that the code is not working.